# NetworkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid is not getting proper data for given time Interval

Tags: android, networkstatsmanager

1) I am checking on Nougat, I already have following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

2) Code Snipet

```
    public long getPackageRxBytesWifi() {
    NetworkStats networkStats = null;
    NetworkStats.Bucket bucket;
    long totalData= 0;
    try {
        networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                "",
                1488441600 ,
                1488902400 ,
                packageUid);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    do {
        bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
        networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
        Log.i("abc", "Start Time Stamp: " + bucket.getStartTimeStamp());
        Log.i("abc", "End Time Stamp: " + bucket.getEndTimeStamp());
        totalData= totalData+ bucket.getRxBytes() + bucket.getTxBytes();
    }while (networkStats.hasNextBucket());
    return totalData;
```

3) When I gives interval 
Start Time - 0
 End Time - `System.currentTimeMillis()`, getting proper data.
But when I gives other time interval
Start Time - 1488441600 (2 march)
 End Time - 1488902400 (7 march 11;30)
 Above method is returning 0.
And  `bucket.getEndTimeStamp()` and `bucket.getStartTimeStamp()` getting printed in Log as 0.
Anyone know how to get data from above query for specific time interval
Please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you are actually passing in seconds when it should be in milliseconds.  Below I've converted your times to milliseconds.  Could you try adjusting your code to the following?

```
try {
        networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                "",
                1488441600000L ,
                1488902400000L ,
                packageUid);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, John. Its working.